# User object is getting populated but Auth.currentSession is returning "No user found"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

When the user clicks on the "sign-in" button and if user.challangeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED'is true, I redirect the user to a page (form screen) where he can provide the input for required attributes and a new password. Even tho the user object is getting populated upon clicking on the sign-in button, using Auth.currentsession on the form screen will print "No user found"

Can someone let me know why I'm seeing no user? What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my login function (triggered when clicked on sign-in button) where I direct the user to the change password screen (form screen) if user.challangeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED' is true.

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);

        if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
            navigate('/change-password');
            return;
        }

        if (user) {
            setToken(user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken);

            const userDetails = await getAccountDetails();

            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN,
                payload: {
                    user: {
                        attributes: user.attributes,
                        username: user.username
                    },
                    client: userDetails
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        await logout();

        throw error;
    }
};
```

Here's my onSubmit function on the change password screen where eventually I want to use **Auth.completeNewPassword** to update the user's password in Cognito

```
 const onSubmitClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (validateFields());

        Auth.currentSession()
            .then((user) => console.log(user))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    };
```

Here's the documentation provided by AWS https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#forgot-password, and the code provided by AWS to update password

```
Auth.signIn(username, password)
.then(user => {
    if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
        const { requiredAttributes } = user.challengeParam; // the array of required attributes, e.g ['email', 'phone_number']
        Auth.completeNewPassword(
            user,               // the Cognito User Object
            newPassword,       // the new password
            // OPTIONAL, the required attributes
            {
              email: 'xxxx@example.com',
              phone_number: '1234567890'
            }
        ).then(user => {
            // at this time the user is logged in if no MFA required
            console.log(user);
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    } else {
        // other situations
    }
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Does replacing `.then((user) => console.log(user))` with `.then(user => {console.log(user)})` makes a difference?

Comment: You seem to have the `user` object in hand (from `await Auth.signIn(...)`). Why do you need to call `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` to get the user? Example code [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#change-password) to change the password.

Answer (score 0):

New updated answer to reflect your updated post, change the `onSubmitClick` to the following:

```
const onSubmitClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (validateFields());

    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user))
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

You are looking at the documentation which shows how to use the user after `Auth.signIn()` (which was my previous answer), compared to what you use: `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`. The proper documentation example you have to look at is this one: https://www.docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js

Comment: I don't want the user to log in, I want him to be redirected to a page ( using useNavigate) where he's going to provide the required attributes and a new password. The code that I had looked like this before adjusting                                                         
   if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
           navigate('/change-password');
                return;
            }

Comment: Where exactly in your old code are you trying to redirect the user? If `useNavigate` is to be used somewhere you should indicate that in your example so we can tell what exactly isn't working.

Comment: @DorukKirali check my updated answer, is this where you want to see the user and use `useNavigate`? Give it a go and let me know if it is still not working.

Comment: just updated my original post and added more details, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @DorukKirali Please have a look at my updated answer and test it. The difference is that you are looking at the documentation which shows how to use the user after `Auth.signIn()` compared to what you use: `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`. The proper documentation example you have to look at is this one: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/

Comment: When I try Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(), I'm seeing "the user is not authenticated" on the console. I just don't get how the user object is getting populated on the login page but the moment I switch to change password screen, the user becomes unauthourized.

Comment: Did you copy and use my code? In your Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() you are not getting the user correctly.

Comment: Yes, copied your code and after filling out the required fields to call the onSubmit function, it prints "the user is not authenticated".